# Find Middle Object in Nested Has Many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have setup an association where my entities are defined such that

Project has many Teams, Team has many Users

I have a project object and I need to find which team a user belongs to. So if I were in the console, I would like to be able to do this:

```
project = Project.find(5)
project.team_id_for_user_id(7)
```

Is there a simple rails way to do this or do I need to iterate through the project teams and then iterate through each of the team users until I find the user's ID and then return the team ID for the current team?

My terminology is probably not correct here which is likely the reason I haven't been able to find an answer elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the association between `Team` and `User`.
Can a User belong to more than one team? If yes, what if the teams are linked to the same project?

Option 1, simple:

```
class Project
  has_many :teams
end

class Team
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :users
end

class User
  belongs_to :team
end

user_id = 7
@team = User.find_by(id: user_id).team
```

Option 2, more complex:

```
class Project
  has_many :teams
end

class Team
  belongs_to :project
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
end


@project = Project.find_by(id: 5)
user_id = 7
@user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
@team = @user.teams.where(project_id: @project.id).first
```

On the last line, the query `@user.teams.where(project_id: @project.id)` will return a single `Team` record if the user is part to a single team per project (you need to have some custom validation in place).

However, if users can be part of different teams for the same project, that query can return more than one record.

Comment: Ok. Yes. Your second more complex example is what I was looking for. And a user can only belong to one team and therefore one project so this will work perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. However, if as you say, "_a user can only belong to one team and therefore one project_", then you might be better off with the associations I outlined in the first example.

Comment: I was realizing after your first example that it is more complicated than I expressed in my question. I use a join model (has_many, through) called team_membership. Team belongs to project, and has many members through team_memberships. Project has many teams. User has many teams through team_membership. User also has many participant projects through teams, source Project. User also has many projects because user's own projects, however, that's inconsequential for the part of the association we're talking about here. Regardless, your second example works great! ;-)